# How to make sure a number is float in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

io:format throws a badarg exception if the format is ~f but the argument is integer:

```
io:format("~f", [2]).
```

Adding 0.0 solves the problem bus there an elegant way?

```
io:format("~f", [2+0.0]).
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- [float(Number)](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#float-1) convert Number to float
- [list_to_float(String)](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_float-1) convert String to float
- [is_float(Term)](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#is_float-1) returns true if Term is a float

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about the exact output, you can use:

```
io:format("~p", [Term]).
```

This will work with any term, but doesn't give you the same kind of formatting options as ~f would.

Answer (score 2):

Either

```
io:format("~f", [2.0]).
```

or

```
io:format("~f", [float(2)]).
```

works.